# How to determine why tsc is compiling a subdirectory

Tags: typescript

I have a project arranged like so:

```
project/
  client/
    src/
      client.ts
    tsconfig.client.json
  src/
    index.ts
  tsconfig.json
```

When I run `tsc -b` in the `project` folder, it is attempting to compile the `client` subdirectory as well. Now I understand that if there is a `tsconfig.json` in a subfolder, then --build will build that folder, but in this case the subdirectory's tsconfig is renamed.

As a result though, tsc outputs an error:

```
error TS5083: Cannot read file 'project/client/tsconfig.json'.
```

How can I go about tracing why tsc is trying to load this folder? `client` is not listed in the `references` in the top level tsconfig, and the `include` and `rootDir` options are set to only build `src`.

I've tried doing a --dry build and a --traceResolution but neither provide a helpful answer.

##### Edit to show my tsconfigs:

`project/tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "extends": "../../../tsconfig.base.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "dist",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "target": "es6",
    "lib": ["es2019","dom"],
    "jsx": "react",
    "noUnusedLocals": false
  },
  "include": ["./src/**/*"],
  "references": [
    { "path": "shared/api" },
    { "path": "../../lib/logger" },
  ]
}
```

`../../../tsconfig.base.json`

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "target": "es2020",
      "module": "commonjs",
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "rootDir": "packages",
      "baseUrl": "./packages",
      "lib": ["es2019"],
  
      "strict": true,
      "noUnusedLocals": true,
      "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
      "noImplicitReturns": true,
      "esModuleInterop": true,
      "allowJs": true,
  
      "composite": true,
      "inlineSources": true,
      "sourceMap": true,
      "incremental": true,

      "skipLibCheck": true,
      "emitDeclarationOnly": true,
  
      "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
      "experimentalDecorators": true,
  
      "newLine": "lf",
  
      "noEmitOnError": true,
    },
    "exclude": ["**/jest.config.js", "**/dist", "**/__mocks__/**/*", "**/coverage", "**/gulpfile.js"]
}
```

`client/tsconfig.client.json` - if it's relevant, since tsc isn't even using this file

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "types": [
      "webpack-env",
      "jest"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "src/*"
      ]
    },
    "lib": [
      "esnext",
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "scripthost",
      "webworker"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx",
    "src/**/*.vue",
    "tests/**/*.ts",
    "tests/**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "references": [
    { "path": "../shared/api" },
    { "path": "../" }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Have you tried explicitly excluding `client`?

Comment: There's also a `--verbose` option which you can try.

Comment: I've tried explicitly excluding `client`. Doesn't work. `--verbose` makes it appear that tsc is doing two separate builds - It shows all the output for the top level build, then at the end shows `Projects in this build: * tsconfig.json` then errors out since it can't find that file.

Comment: Can you share the contents of your `tsconfig.json`?

Comment: Edited the question to include these now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I discovered is that I was running the `tsc` command using `npx`. Since I have workspaces set up in my monorepo, the subfolder had a package.json which npm was picking up and running the tsc command a second time in the subfolder.

Updating my npx command to `npx --workspaces=false tsc -b` fixes the problem.